# What responds to a ping? The modem, or the router?

Tags: router, ping

Just a very simple question I'm sure you all know.

When I ping my public IP address what is responding to the ping?

Is my modem responding to the ping and never reaching the router or is the modem just passing it to the router and the router responds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as usual, modem works on layer1-2(OSI model), and it is just pass layer 3 traffic to the router. what model of the modem, do you have?

Comment: I have an ARRIS modem model TM822. So from my understanding of your post then the router is doing the responding to the ping?

Comment: yes, router is responding on the ping

Comment: it may be useful: if you will change your router, you must register it(call to you ISP), as usual, ISP register mac address of the connected to the modem router